# Alternate to message_tags while posting on groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

I see we can NOT use html while posting a post to groups,
and the tag message_tags is only a readonly value.

bug status says by design!
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/247911678652789

I need to tag users in the posts I'm making , 
needed to ask if there is an alternative available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, like I said on that bug report, there is currently no way to add tags to posts via the API